# How to auto accept changes in chromatic github workflow for main branch?

Tags: reactjs, github, github-actions, chromatic

In Chromatic github workflow, how can I accept all changes automatically using the CLI option `--auto-accept-changes` if the branch is `main`?

I am using the following [github chromatic workflow](https://www.chromatic.com/docs/github-actions) to deploy the components of my app in chromatic:

```yaml
# .github/workflows/chromatic.yml

# Workflow name
name: 'Chromatic'

# Event for the workflow
on: push

# List of jobs
jobs:
  chromatic-deployment:
    # Operating System
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    # Job steps
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: yarn
        #  Adds Chromatic as a step in the workflow
      - name: Publish to Chromatic
        uses: chromaui/action@v1
        # Chromatic GitHub Action options
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.REPO_GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          #  Chromatic projectToken, refer to the manage page to obtain it.
          projectToken: ${{ secrets.CHROMATIC_PROJECT_TOKEN }}
```

The branch detection appears [in the docs](https://www.chromatic.com/docs/custom-ci-provider#squashrebase-merge-and-the-master-branch), but Im not sure how to use it in my yml file, since my action is just `yarn`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `autoAcceptChanges` where you can define flag or branch name

```
- uses: chromaui/action@v1
  with:
    token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
    projectToken: 'Your chromatic project token'
    buildScriptName: 'The npm script that builds your Storybook [build-storybook]'
    storybookBuildDir: 'Provide a directory with your built storybook; use if you've already built your storybook'
    allowConsoleErrors: 'Do not exit when runtime errors occur in storybook'
    autoAcceptChanges: 'Automatically accept all changes in chromatic: boolean or branchname'
    exitZeroOnChanges: 'Positive exit of action even when there are changes: boolean or branchname'
    exitOnceUploaded: 'Exit with 0 once the built version has been sent to chromatic: boolean or branchname'
```

so it should be:

```yaml
# .github/workflows/chromatic.yml

# Workflow name
name: 'Chromatic'

# Event for the workflow
on: push

# List of jobs
jobs:
  chromatic-deployment:
    # Operating System
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    # Job steps
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: yarn
        #  Adds Chromatic as a step in the workflow
      - name: Publish to Chromatic
        uses: chromaui/action@v1
        # Chromatic GitHub Action options
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.REPO_GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          #  Chromatic projectToken, refer to the manage page to obtain it.
          projectToken: ${{ secrets.CHROMATIC_PROJECT_TOKEN }}
          autoAcceptChanges: 'main'
```

Comment: @Rashomon Can you consider upvoting my reply if it was helpful for you?